# Not able to load all variables in r using the read.table function

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing seven columns and 100 rows but when I use the function read.table only six columns with 103 rows are loaded into r. In the last column only three points are given but I dont really understand why the read.table function does not give a table with 7 columns and 100 rows.

The data looks like this:

```
0   484  1712   4278    3294    132 
0   494  1776   4388    3132    110 
0   494  1764   4404    3138    100 
0   490  1740   4256    3274    140 
0   484  1678   4156    3434    148 
0   490  1750   4446    3116    98  
0   478  1642   4032    3486    262 
0   490  1764   4440    3126    80  
0   482  1626   3902    3500    390 
0   496  1804   4498    3008    94
```

The first value that is given in the 7th column is given in the 14th row.

Comment: Could be delimiters, quotes, headers... anyway to share the file? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: can you paste the 1st 10 rows in your question ? Also, try using `data.table::fread` instead of `read.table`

Comment: Please click on [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50483124/edit) to edit your post.

Comment: The data example that you posted only has six columns, not seven.